# next() is not a function error Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var middleware = {
    requireAuthentication: function(req, res, next){
        console.log("private route hit");
        next();
    }
};

app.use(middleware.requireAuthentication());


app.get('/about',

    function(req, res){
    res.send('You clicked on about!');

    }

);  
var projectDir = __dirname + '/public'; 
app.use(express.static(projectDir));
app.listen(3000), function(){
    console.log('Static service started');

};
```

I get the error (when trying to run the server) that `next()` is not a function. I've been following a tutorial on Nodejs and it works just fine for them. What is the issue I am having here?

Comment: `foo(bar())` always calls `bar` first and passes the return value to `foo`. `requireAuthentication` is not supposed to be called by you.

Answer (score 20):

This line:

```
app.use(middleware.requireAuthentication());
```

**calls** your method and passes its return value into `app.use`. You're not calling it with any arguments, so naturally the `next` parameter is `undefined.`

Get rid of the `()` so you're passing the function, not its result, into `app.use`:

```
app.use(middleware.requireAuthentication);
// No () here --------------------------^
```